# Does Cold Blooded affect all players?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Quoting the [skill description](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/passive/cold-blooded):

> All damage dealt to chilled and frozen targets is increased by 20%.

Does "All Damage" mean it applies to damage dealt by other players?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it means all damage dealt by you.

Comment: Source: I play wizard